# Shader is not working properly in my 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was looking for doing a sprite wave like water on a lake/ocean, i found a tutorial on internet, but it was for a 3d game, i applied the tutorial but the shader is moving the sprite in the Z axis, so the wave effect is not notizable from 2d view, but in 3d view it looks fine, it's a 2d game so i need it to move in the correct direcction, this is my first shader so i don't understand it so much.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want, but try using a x=0, y=1, z=0 vector instead of the `Normal Vector` node.  That should make the wave motion go in the "upward" direction on the object instead of the "outward" direction.

Comment: i'll try that, i'm sorry for it, it's something really new for me

Comment: It was simple as that just replacing the Normal Vector, thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a x=0, y=1, z=0 vector instead of the Normal Vector node.

That will make the wave motion go in the "upward" direction on the object instead of the "outward" direction.